# Read docx file in Ironpython

Tags: python, ironpython

Is it possible to download Docx package to 'Iron Python'?If not, is there another option to read docx file in 'Iron Python?

Could not find relevant info in google.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you want to read from the docx? Have you looked at closedxml/openxml? That might be the dotnet way of doing that.

Comment: I need to write similar script (loop in document and replace word),                         
document = Document("F10352-JB117-FM102 Pile CTSV-01 As-built Memo Issue 1-Trial (002).docx")                                                                                                                                      for table in document.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                if 'Mickymouse' in paragraph.text:
                    paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace("Mickymouse",'pp')

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/325 ? The docx package might work. Otherwise you could look at https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK or https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The solution I used is that I have run the python file inside of iron python via the package namely subprocess.